# Issue with drawing over buttons in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const color = document.querySelector("#color");
    const strokeWeight = document.querySelector("#strokeWeight");
    const eraser = document.querySelector('#eraser');
    //variables
    const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear");

    let painting = false;

    function startPosition(e) {
      painting = true;
      draw(e);
    }
    function finishedPosition() {
      painting = false;
      ctx.beginPath();
    }

    function draw(e) {
      if(e.which == 1) {
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      } else {
      finishedPosition();
      }

    }

    function changeColor(e) {
      const color = e.target.value;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    }

    function changeStrokeWeight(e) {
        const strokeWeight = e.target.value;
        ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;
    }

    function clickEraser() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    }


    //Event listeners
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);

    color.addEventListener("input", changeColor);
    strokeWeight.addEventListener("input", changeStrokeWeight);
    eraser.addEventListener("click", clickEraser);
    //Buttons
    clearButton.addEventListener("click", clearCanvas);

    function clearCanvas() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
function resizeCanvas() {
    //Resizing
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
}
resizeCanvas();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
    border: 0.0001px solid white;
}

html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#clear {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 30px;
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border-width: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: red;
}

#clear:hover {
    transition: 0.4s;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#clear:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#eraser {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 30px;
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border-width: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: red;
}

#eraser:hover {
    transition: 0.4s;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#eraser:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#eraser img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

#colorChoice {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.5rem;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#colorChoice:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#strokeWeightChoice {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3rem;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#strokeWeight {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Paint, Inc.</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sideNav">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
    <button id="clear" title="Clear">X</button>
    <button id="eraser" title="Eraser"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-object/74/24-512.png" alt="eraser"></button>

    <section id="colorChoice">
        <input id="color" type="color" value="#000000" />
        <label id="colorLabel" for="color">Color</label>
    </section>

    <section id="strokeWeightChoice">
        <input id="strokeWeight" type="range" min="1" max="51" step="5" value="1" list="tickmarks">
        <label for="strokeWeight">Thickness</label>
        <datalist id="tickmarks">
            <option value="1"></option>
            <option value="6"></option>
            <option value="11"></option>
            <option value="16"></option>
            <option value="21"></option>
            <option value="26"></option>
            <option value="31"></option>
            <option value="36"></option>
            <option value="41"></option>
            <option value="46"></option>
            <option value="51"></option>
        </datalist>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I draw and hover over the buttons, I can draw over the buttons but I don't want that. With the clear button and eraser button when I increase the thickness I can draw over the buttons. Is there anything to stop this from occurring. Is there any border I can add around the button or anything that doesn't show on the canvas but blocks this from happening.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and specialy https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You've set alpha using `rgba` on these elements so they're transparent. Remove the alpha. Another approach is put them to the left and right of the canvas element instead of using an absolute position to put them on top of the canvas.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the alpha which caused the transparency, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you simply miss `&& painting` in

```
function draw(e) {   // draw
  if (e.which == 1 && painting) {
```